# django - adding object to manytomany: Cannot add "<object>": the value for field "other object" is None

Tags: django, django-views

I am using a form to retrieve a TextField.  I then parse each line of the textfield to create students and save a `Student` object. Finally I add students to a `Classroom` object. This worked when student was a foreignkey to classroom. I changed this relationship to a ManyToMany relationship and now I get the error: `Cannot add "<Student: name>": the value for field "student" is None`.

**Models**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    student_first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_last = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    attend = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    do_not_pick = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    student_number = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

class Classroom(models.Model):
    """The gradebook is split into courses, classes and students"""
    classroom_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**View**

```
def addmultistudent(request, classroom_id):
    """Add multiple students at once."""
    classblock = get_object_or_404(Classroom, pk=classroom_id)
    context = {'classblock': classblock}
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentInputForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            s = form.save()
            input_list = []
            input_list = s.name_list.split('\n')

            # the for returns a list of students with student number, fisrt_name, last_name in each line
            for line in input_list:
                # remove the carriage return
                line = line.strip('\r')
                # removes double quotes
                line = line.translate({ord(c): None for c in '"'})
                # ignore the first line which is a header starting with "Pupil"
                if not line.startswith("Pupil"):
                    # get rid of the commas from the csv file
                    all_names = line.split(",")
                    # pop the studnet number
                    sn = all_names.pop(0)

                    # make sure the student not already been added
                    if not Student.objects.filter(student_number=sn).exists():
                        first = all_names.pop(0)
                        last = ""
                        for name in all_names:
                            last = last + name + " "
                        last = last[:-1]
                        # create the object and then add the attributes
                        email_add = sn + "@bc.ca"
                        nick = first + last[0]
                        full = first + " " + last
                        new_student = Student(student_last=last, student_first=first,
                                            student_number=sn, nickname=nick, fullname=full, email=email_add)
                        print(new_student)
                        print(classblock)
                        new_student.save()
                        classblock.students.add(new_student)
                        # attach student to a user
                        if not User.objects.filter(username=sn):
                            user = User.objects.create_user(sn, email_add)
                            user.last_name = last
                            user.first_name = first
                            user.save()

                    # if the student has been added, we just need to add them to the new classroom
                    else:
                        new_student = Student.objects.get(student_number=sn)
                        classblock.students.add(new_student)


            form = StudentInputForm(None)
            context['form'] = form
            return render(request, "gradebook/addmultistudent.html", context)

        else:
            context['form'] = form
            return render(request, "gradebook/addmultistudent.html", context)
```

The `print(new_student)` and `print(classblock)` print the expected objects in the terminal, and later when I go to the admin page I can see that they exist.  If I then go into the django shell, I can type the commands:

```
c1 = Classroom.objects.all().first()
s1 = Student.objects.all().first()
c1.students.add(s1)
```

And the student s1 does get added to the classroom. FWIW I'm testing this with only one student and classroom object so far, so s1 and c1 correspond to objects referred to in my error.

Is this a timing error, where I can't add an object to a m2m relationship immediately after saving it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Need to save user before saving student

`Student` has a `user` OneToOne field.  If I save the user object first, the `new_student.save()` works.

```
# attach student to a user
if not User.objects.filter(username=sn):
    user = User.objects.create_user(sn, email_add)
    user.last_name = last
    user.first_name = first
    user.save()
new_student.save()
classblock.students.add(new_student)
```